# how to write code for user task in JBPM

Tags: java, drools, jbpm

I am a newbie when it comes to JBPM. And while I have created the sample application with a script task and user task. When I remove user task the bpmn is executing fine. But when I keep UserTask it is throwing an exception.

Following is my code:

```
package com.Sservlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import org.drools.KnowledgeBase;
import org.drools.SystemEventListenerFactory;
import org.drools.builder.*;
import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory;
import org.drools.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession;
import org.drools.runtime.process.ProcessInstance;
import org.jbpm.bpmn2.handler.ServiceTaskHandler;
import org.jbpm.process.workitem.wsht.CommandBasedWSHumanTaskHandler;
import org.jbpm.task.*;
import org.jbpm.task.service.*;

public class SServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();

        kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("Jcr.bpmn2"), ResourceType.BPMN2);

        KnowledgeBase kbase = kbuilder.newKnowledgeBase();
        StatefulKnowledgeSession ksession = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();
        CommandBasedWSHumanTaskHandler taskHandler = new CommandBasedWSHumanTaskHandler(ksession);

        ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task", new ServiceTaskHandler());

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jbpm.task");
        TaskService taskService = new TaskService(emf, SystemEventListenerFactory.getSystemEventListener());
        TaskServiceSession taskSession = taskService.createSession();

        // now register new users and groups
        List list = taskSession.getTasksAssignedAsPotentialOwner("John", "en-UK");
        taskHandler.connect();
        ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("TestHandle");

        System.out.println("hello here are");
    }
}
```

I am receiving a No Persistence provider exception:

> `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named org.jbpm.task`

I don't need any database insertion here. It is a simple user-task. Is there any solution?

Comment: What kind of staggered code format is that? **Edit:** I fixed the formatting.

Comment: The line: `EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.jbpm.task");` is saying that you have an Entity Manager called, *"org.jbpm.task"*, but it cannot find it.

Comment: Thank you..But i have already uploaded the jar.